# not defined structures in directx

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I am having some trouble compiling my directX project I made.
My project is based on a simple directX 11 library I made. The library compiles without anny error but when I try to compile the actual program I get errors that directX structures are not defined.
I am not sure if it is relevant but I added the windows sdk(7.1) manualy.
I also noticed that all the errors are either in d3d11shader.h or D3Dcompiler.h , I don't know if it has something to do with my problem.

Here is the errors I get(unfortunatly I have windows, and therefore Visual studio in German, but I will list some explanation below)

"ist nicht definiert" :
is not defined

"Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt. " :
 int type specificer expected. defautlt int is not supported by c++

"kann nur auf Funktionsdeklarationen oder Funktionsdefinitionen angewendet werden.":
can only be used forfunction declaration/definition

"bei der Deklaration von Daten nicht zulässig":
not legal for the declaration of data

```
117 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DInclude"" ist nicht definiert.   d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    153 21  realLife
121 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DInclude"" ist nicht definiert.   d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    166 6   realLife
125 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DInclude"" ist nicht definiert.   d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    186 24  realLife
129 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DInclude"" ist nicht definiert.   d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    195 6   realLife
118 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DBlob"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    158 18  realLife
119 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DBlob"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    159 22  realLife
122 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DBlob"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    171 6   realLife
123 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DBlob"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    172 6   realLife
126 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DBlob"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    187 21  realLife
127 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DBlob"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    188 25  realLife
130 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DBlob"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    196 6   realLife
131 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DBlob"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    197 6   realLife
132 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DBlob"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    209 23  realLife
133 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DBlob"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    241 22  realLife
134 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DBlob"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    248 12  realLife
135 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DBlob"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    260 30  realLife
136 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DBlob"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    271 32  realLife
137 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DBlob"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    282 33  realLife
138 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DBlob"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    293 41  realLife
139 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DBlob"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    313 22  realLife
140 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DBlob"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    345 22  realLife
141 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DBlob"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    365 26  realLife
142 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DBlob"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    380 48  realLife
143 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ID3DBlob"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    391 21  realLife
114 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""D3D_TESSELLATOR_PARTITIONING"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3D11Shader.h    92  9   realLife
115 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""D3D_TESSELLATOR_OUTPUT_PRIMITIVE"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3D11Shader.h    94  9   realLife
113 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""D3D_TESSELLATOR_DOMAIN"" ist nicht definiert.    d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3D11Shader.h    90  9   realLife
116 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""D3D_SHADER_MACRO"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    152 58  realLife
120 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""D3D_SHADER_MACRO"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    165 12  realLife
124 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""D3D_SHADER_MACRO"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    185 30  realLife
128 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""D3D_SHADER_MACRO"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3Dcompiler.h    194 12  realLife
111 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""D3D_RESOURCE_RETURN_TYPE"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3D11Shader.h    35  9   realLife
112 IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""D3D_CBUFFER_TYPE"" ist nicht definiert.  d:\CPPQuellcode\SDKs\directx11\Include\D3D11Shader.h    37  9   realLife 
Fehler  4   error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    35  1   realLife
Fehler  6   error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    37  1   realLife
Fehler  8   error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    45  1   realLife
Fehler  10  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    46  1   realLife
Fehler  12  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    80  1   realLife
Fehler  14  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    81  1   realLife
Fehler  16  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    90  1   realLife
Fehler  18  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    92  1   realLife
Fehler  20  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    94  1   realLife
Fehler  22  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    126 1   realLife
Fehler  24  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    128 1   realLife
Fehler  26  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    144 1   realLife
Fehler  28  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    150 1   realLife
Fehler  31  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    271 1   realLife
Fehler  35  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    152 1   realLife
Fehler  37  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    165 1   realLife
Fehler  39  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    185 1   realLife
Fehler  41  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    194 1   realLife
Fehler  60  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    35  1   realLife
Fehler  62  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    37  1   realLife
Fehler  64  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    45  1   realLife
Fehler  66  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    46  1   realLife
Fehler  68  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    80  1   realLife
Fehler  70  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    81  1   realLife
Fehler  72  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    90  1   realLife
Fehler  74  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    92  1   realLife
Fehler  76  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    94  1   realLife
Fehler  78  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    126 1   realLife
Fehler  80  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    128 1   realLife
Fehler  82  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    144 1   realLife
Fehler  84  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    150 1   realLife
Fehler  87  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    271 1   realLife
Fehler  91  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    152 1   realLife
Fehler  93  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    165 1   realLife
Fehler  95  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    185 1   realLife
Fehler  97  error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    194 1   realLife
Fehler  32  error C2495: "ID3D11ShaderReflection::D3D_PRIMITIVE": "__declspec(nothrow)" kann nur auf Funktionsdeklarationen oder Funktionsdefinitionen angewendet werden.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    271 1   realLife
Fehler  88  error C2495: "ID3D11ShaderReflection::D3D_PRIMITIVE": "__declspec(nothrow)" kann nur auf Funktionsdeklarationen oder Funktionsdefinitionen angewendet werden.   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    271 1   realLife
Fehler  30  error C2433: 'ID3D11ShaderReflection::D3D_PRIMITIVE': 'virtual' bei der Deklaration von Daten nicht zulässig    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    271 1   realLife
Fehler  86  error C2433: 'ID3D11ShaderReflection::D3D_PRIMITIVE': 'virtual' bei der Deklaration von Daten nicht zulässig    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    271 1   realLife
Fehler  34  error C2253: "ID3D11ShaderReflection::GetGSInputPrimitive": Ein reiner Spezifizierer oder ein abstrakter Überschreibungsspezifizierer ist nur für eine virtuelle Funktion zulässig. d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    271 1   realLife
Fehler  90  error C2253: "ID3D11ShaderReflection::GetGSInputPrimitive": Ein reiner Spezifizierer oder ein abstrakter Überschreibungsspezifizierer ist nur für eine virtuelle Funktion zulässig. d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    271 1   realLife
Fehler  13  error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'Type'  d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    81  1   realLife
Fehler  25  error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'Type'  d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    144 1   realLife
Fehler  69  error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'Type'  d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    81  1   realLife
Fehler  81  error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'Type'  d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    144 1   realLife
Fehler  7   error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'SystemValueType'   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    45  1   realLife
Fehler  63  error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'SystemValueType'   d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    45  1   realLife
Fehler  23  error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'InputPrimitive'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    128 1   realLife
Fehler  79  error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'InputPrimitive'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    128 1   realLife
Fehler  21  error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'GSOutputTopology'  d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    126 1   realLife
Fehler  77  error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'GSOutputTopology'  d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    126 1   realLife
Fehler  27  error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'Dimension' d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    150 1   realLife
Fehler  83  error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'Dimension' d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    150 1   realLife
Fehler  17  error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'D3D11_TESSELLATOR_PARTITIONING'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    92  1   realLife
Fehler  73  error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'D3D11_TESSELLATOR_PARTITIONING'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    92  1   realLife
Fehler  19  error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'D3D11_TESSELLATOR_OUTPUT_PRIMITIVE'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    94  1   realLife
Fehler  75  error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'D3D11_TESSELLATOR_OUTPUT_PRIMITIVE'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    94  1   realLife
Fehler  15  error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'D3D11_TESSELLATOR_DOMAIN'  d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    90  1   realLife
Fehler  71  error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'D3D11_TESSELLATOR_DOMAIN'  d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    90  1   realLife
Fehler  3   error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'D3D11_RESOURCE_RETURN_TYPE'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    35  1   realLife
Fehler  59  error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'D3D11_RESOURCE_RETURN_TYPE'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    35  1   realLife
Fehler  5   error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'D3D11_CBUFFER_TYPE'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    37  1   realLife
Fehler  61  error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'D3D11_CBUFFER_TYPE'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    37  1   realLife
Fehler  9   error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'ComponentType' d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    46  1   realLife
Fehler  65  error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'ComponentType' d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    46  1   realLife
Fehler  11  error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'Class' d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    80  1   realLife
Fehler  67  error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'Class' d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    80  1   realLife
Fehler  29  error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ';' vor '__stdcall' d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    271 1   realLife
Fehler  85  error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ';' vor '__stdcall' d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3d11shader.h    271 1   realLife
Fehler  36  error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ',' vor '*' d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    152 1   realLife
Fehler  38  error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ',' vor '*' d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    165 1   realLife
Fehler  40  error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ',' vor '*' d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    185 1   realLife
Fehler  42  error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ',' vor '*' d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    194 1   realLife
Fehler  92  error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ',' vor '*' d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    152 1   realLife
Fehler  94  error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ',' vor '*' d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    165 1   realLife
Fehler  96  error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ',' vor '*' d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    185 1   realLife
Fehler  98  error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ',' vor '*' d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    194 1   realLife
Fehler  43  error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    209 1   realLife
Fehler  44  error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    241 1   realLife
Fehler  45  error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    248 1   realLife
Fehler  46  error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    260 1   realLife
Fehler  47  error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    271 1   realLife
Fehler  48  error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    282 1   realLife
Fehler  49  error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    293 1   realLife
Fehler  50  error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    313 1   realLife
Fehler  51  error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    345 1   realLife
Fehler  52  error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    365 1   realLife
Fehler  53  error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    380 1   realLife
Fehler  54  error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    391 1   realLife
Fehler  99  error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    209 1   realLife
Fehler  100 error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    241 1   realLife
Fehler  101 error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    248 1   realLife
Fehler  102 error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    260 1   realLife
Fehler  103 error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    271 1   realLife
Fehler  104 error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    282 1   realLife
Fehler  105 error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    293 1   realLife
Fehler  106 error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    313 1   realLife
Fehler  107 error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    345 1   realLife
Fehler  108 error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    365 1   realLife
Fehler  109 error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    380 1   realLife
Fehler  110 error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner 'ID3DBlob'    d:\cppquellcode\sdks\directx11\include\d3dcompiler.h    391 1   realLife
```

Thanks in advance for responses, and just let me know if you need more information or some more Greman -> English translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error I surfed some more and found an interesting post.
The problem I had was because apperently the windows 7 SDK already contains (at least some parts of the DirectX SDK), and because of the order I set the aditional include libraries it searched in the windows SDK first.
What I had to do was change the order of these directories so directx was above windows.
Sorry for asking I should have made more research.

Comment: See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) and [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/).